# Need advice about memory management

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I have been working with Objective-C for a month approximately but regretfully I'm still a complete dummy in memory management so I need your advice. I pass an array from one file to the other like this

```
         BidView *bidView = [[[BidView alloc] init] autorelease];
         NSLog(@"%i",[bidView.seatsForTableCreated retainCount]);
         bidView.seatsForTableCreated = [NSArray arrayWithArray:seats];
         NSLog(@"%i",[bidView.seatsForTableCreated retainCount]);
         [self.navigationController pushViewController:bidView animated:YES];  `
```

NSLog tells me that retain count of seatsForTableCreated has raised from zero to two. Then, when I quit the BidView screen (without doing anything with seatsForTableCreated array) I' m doing the following:

```
NSLog(@"%i",[seatsForTableCreated retainCount]);
[seatsForTableCreated release];
NSLog(@"%i",[seatsForTableCreated retainCount]);
```

it's quite unclear for me. Now NSLog tells me (both times) that retain count is 1. Then I repeat this procedure (running the same application I mean) and each time things are the same:0-2-1-1.  So my questions are:
 1)Why 0 to 2? Why retain count increases to 2 not to 1? 
 2)why then it drops to 1 without being impacted in any way?
 3)Why it still remains 1 after i've released it? 
 4)How would you manage the memory in such a case?
Great thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice assumes you are using Xcode 4+ and you are not using ARC,

command+shift+B will analyse your memory management (and dead stores and such). I think you got it right. Don't worry about the retain counts so much until you get a complaint from Analyze or find leaks with Instruments.  I am not sure how reliable retain counts are. I have seen comments on SO saying not to rely on them.

You are following the rules well
New, Alloc, Copy, Retain --> You will need to release this object when you are done with it.

I am also assuming in BidView.h your property is declared as
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSArray * seatsForTableCreated;

So releasing that in the dealloc method in BidView.m is good memory management

EDIT
It works when even though you don't allocate seats for table created because.
`self.seatsForTableCreated = ...`  will retain whatever object you are setting there.
So if you have a property with (retain) in the declaration, you can consider

```
self.property = object;
```

as setting property and retaining it.  The properties were added to objective-C to reduce similar code being in every class.

A property in .h

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSObject * property; // don't name your properties property..
```

Compiler will create 2 methods for you automatically when you `@synthesize` in the .m

```
-(void)setProperty:(NSObject*)newP
{
    [newP retain];  // retains the new object so it sticks around for line 3
    [property release]; // releases previous property
    property = newP; // set the property to the object retained in line 1
    // property is now same as newP and you are responsible for releasing it
    // -(void) dealloc   is where you should release it
}
```

// Note, the compiler may not create the exact same code as above when creating the //setProperty method. If it does, it could be subject to change.

```
-(NSObject*)property
{
    return property;
}
```

I tried to figure out why Analyze isn't catching the issue when you don't release your property, but haven't.  That is confusing and I want to explore it further.

Comment: All you assumptions are correct: i'm using Xcode 4 and i declared my array as property just like you wrote. I use Product->Analyze and it tells me everything's OK, no memory leaks. I put [seatsForTableCreated release] in BidView.m dealloc method. Seems like all is fine, but how does it work if i HAVE NOT ALLOCATED seatsForTableCreated? How can it contain an object? Why should i release it? If i never release seatsForTableCreated Product -> Analyze also says there's no memory leaks in my app... It's really confusing

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost. Don't call nor use `retainCount` for nothing, think about this property as private and only the OS can call. To check if you have a memory leak you should use Instruments.

Seems like you've created an autoreleasing (`[NSArray arrayWithArray:seats]`) object, so you **can't** manually release it.

And use the Allocations Instrument to really check if you have a memory leak.

Comment: He sets the array to a property and it is more than likely retained there.  So the class BidView that has that property (seatsForTableCreated) should release that array.

Comment: Quite right. The _concept_ of retainCount is important, in that you must know which operations increase and decrease it, but the actual value is useless. You should only care about the increases/decreases you are responsible for.